# Does Amazon S3 send invalidation signals to CloudFront?

Tags: amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront

When I update a file on S3 and I have CloudFront enabled, does S3 send an invalidation signal to CloudFront? Or do I need to send it myself after updating the file?

I can't seem to see an obvious answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

S3 doesn't send any invalidation information to CloudFront. By default CloudFront will hold information up to the maximum time specified by the Cache Control headers that were set when it retrieved the data from the origin (it may remove items from its cache earlier if it feels like it).

You can invalidate cache entries by creating an invalidation batch. This will cost you money: the 1st 1000 requests a month are free but beyond that it costs $0.005 per request - if you were invalidating 1000 files a day it would cost you $150 a month (unless you can make use of the wildcard feature). You can of course trigger this in response to an s3 event using an Amazon Lambda function.

Another approach is to use a different path when the object changes (in effect a generational cache key). Similarly you could append a query parameter to the url and change that query parameter when you want cloudfront to fetch a fresh copy (to do this you'll need to tell CloudFront to use query string parameters - by default it ignores them).

Another way if you only do infrequent (but large) changes is to simply create a new cloudfront distribution.

Comment: I had a horrible feeling this was the case. Seems like they missed a feature. Can you provide a reference for that or is it just not specified? Thanks.

Comment: It would be a faulty assumption that uploading a new version to S3 means that you want to clear the cache in CloudFront. Yes, this may be the behavior that you're looking for, but it would be presumptuous of AWS to _assume_ that this is what you want. In many cases, I will cache content in CloudFront knowing that it will expire according to my settings, and will stage updated content in S3 ahead of time. In my case, and automatic invalidation is the opposite of what I want.

Comment: Not assuming, but it seems like a useful parameter to have had.

Comment: @RyanParman just saw your bio so I thought I'd explain a bit more! I totally get the way CloudFront works (and I use it myself with my own origin). I just think that in many cases I can think of there's no point allowing you to re-upload a new resource to S3 without CloudFront being invalidated, especially as S3 and CF are separate but tightly integrated. As S3 has this information ("resource X changed"), my use case (why I'm writing the question) is that I want it to send invalidation. I see your use case, so I suppose we just want to use it for different things. But I'm sure I'm not alone.

Comment: I can certainly raise this up the flagpole as something that the S3 and CloudFront teams should consider in a future feature update. I'll contact those teams now. Thanks!

Comment: @RyanParman, do you know if this feature(automatic invalidation) is out or at list planned?

Comment: Given S3 includes a specific option to serve content as static webpages, I’m surprised it doesn’t include an optional field for a Cloudfront distribution ID and do this automatically

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know, all CDNs work like this.

It's why you generally use something like `foo-x.y.z.ext` to version assets on a CDN. I wouldn't use `foo.ext?x.y.z` because there was something about certain browsers and proxies never caching assets with a `?QUERY_STRING`.

In general you may want to check this out:
https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/best-practices/caching

It contains lots of best practices and goes into details what to do and how it works.

In regard to S3 and Cloudfront, I'm not super familiar with the cache invalidation, but what Frederick Cheung mentioned is all correct.

Some providers also allow you to clear the cache directly but because of the nature of a CDN these changes are almost never instant. Another method is to set a smaller TTL (expiration headers) so assets will be refreshed more often. But I think that defeats the purpose of a CDN as well.

In our case (Edgecast), cache invalidation is possible (a manual process) and free of charge, but we rarely do this because we version our assets accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm familiar with both S3 and CloudFront (and others), I was asking about the specific integration between these two Amazon products.

Comment: OK, I didn't get that specifically. So yeah – my recommendation would be to still version assets and to set `Cache-Control` header on the object.

Comment: Thanks it looks like I'm just going to have to work around it. I still think it's an essential and easy-to-implement feature they missed.