# CloudFront / S3 ETag: Possible for CloudFront to send updated S3 Object before the CF TTL has expired?

Tags: caching, amazon-cloudfront, etag, ttl

I have a question in regard to how CloudFront will use an S3 object's *ETag* to determine if it needs to send a refreshed object or not.

I know that the ETag will be part of the Request to the CloudFront distribution, in my case I'm seeing the "weak" (shortened) version:

```
if-none-match: W/"eabcdef4036c3b4f8fbf1e8aa81502542"
```

If this ETag being sent does not match the S3 Object's current ETag value, then the CloudFront will send the latest version.

I'm seeing this work as expected, but only after the CloudFront's cache policy has been reached.  In my case it's been set to 20 mins.

**CloudFront with a Cache Policy**:

- Minimum TTL: 1
- Maximum TTL: 1200 <-- (20 mins)
- Default TTL: 900
- Origin Request Policy is not set

**S3 Bucket**:

- Set to only allow access via its corresponding CloudFront
  distribution above.
- Bucket and objects not public
- The test object (index.html) in this case has only one header set:
  Content-Type = text/html
- While I am using the CloudFront's Cache Policy, I've also tested
  using the S3 Object header of Cache-Control = max-age=6000
- This had no affect on the refresh of the "index.html" object in
  regard to the ETag check I'm asking about.

**The Scenario**:

Upon first "putObject" to that S3 bucket, the "index.html" file has an ETag of:

```
eabcdef4036c3b4f8fbf1e8aa81502542
```

When I hit the URL (GET) for that "index.html" file, the cache of 20 mins is effectively started.

Subsequent hits to the "index.html" URL (GET) has the Request with the value

```
if-none-match: W/"eabcdef4036c3b4f8fbf1e8aa81502542"
```

I also see "*x-cache: Hit from cloudfront*" in the Response coming back.

Before the 20 mins is up, I'll make a change to the "index.html" file and re-upload via a "putObject" command in my code.

That will then change the ETag to:

```
exyzcde4099c3b4f8fuy1e8aa81501122
```

I would expect then that the next Request to CloudFront, *before* the 20-minute TTL and with the old "*if-none-match*" value, would then prompt the CloudFront to see the ETag is different and send the latest version.

But in all cases/tests it doesn't.  CloudFront will seem to ignore the ETag difference and continue to send the older "index.html" version.

It's only after the 20 mins (cache TTL) is up that the CloudFront sends the latest version.

At that time the ETag in the Request changes/updates as well:

```
if-none-match: W/"exyzcde4099c3b4f8fuy1e8aa81501122"
```

**Question** (*finally*, huh?):

Is there a way to configure CloudFront to listen to the incoming ETag, and if needed, send the latest Object without having to wait for the Cache Policy TTL to expire?

**UPDATE**:

Kevin Henry's response explains it well:

"*CloudFront doesn't know that you updated S3. You told it not to check with the origin until the TTL has expired. So it's just serving the old file until the TTL has expired and it sees the new one that you uploaded to S3. (Note that this doesn't have anything to do with ETags).*"

So I decided to test how the ETag would be used if I turned the CloudFront Caching Policy to a TTL of 0 for all three CloudFront settings.  I know that this defeats the purpose, and one of the strengths, of CloudFront, but I'm still wrapping my head around certain key aspects of CDN caching.

After setting the cache to 0, I'm seeing a continual "*Miss from CloudFront*" in the Response coming back.

I expected this, and in the first response I see a HTTP status of 200.  Note the file size being returned is 128KB for this test.

Subsequent calls to this same file return a HTTP status of 304, with a file size being returned around 400B.

As soon as I update the "index.html" file in the S3 bucket, and call that same URL, the status code is 200 with a file size of 128KB.

Subsequent calls return a status of 304, again with an average of 400B in file size.

Looking again at the definition of an HTTP status of 304:

https://httpstatuses.com/304

"*A conditional GET or HEAD request has been received and would have resulted in a 200 OK response if it were not for the fact that the condition evaluated to false.*

*In other words, there is no need for the server to transfer a representation of the target resource because the request indicates that the client, which made the request conditional, already has a valid representation; the server is therefore redirecting the client to make use of that stored representation as if it were the payload of a 200 OK response.*"

**So am I correct in thinking that I'm using the Browser's cache at this point?**

The calls to the CloudFront will now pass the requests to the Origin, where the ETag is used to verify if the resource has changed.

As it hasn't, then a 304 is returned and the Browser kicks in and returns its stored version of "index.html".

Would this be a correct assumption?

In case you're wondering, I can't use the invalidation method for clearing cache, as my site could expect several thousand invalidations a day. I'm hosting a writing journal site, where the authors could update their files daily, therefore producing new versions of their work on S3.

I would also rather not use the versioning method, with a timestamp or other string added as a query to the page URL.  SEO reasons for this one mainly.

My ideal scenario would be to serve the same version of the author's work until they've updated it, at which time the next call to that same page would show its latest version.

This research/exercise is helping me to learn and weigh my options.

Thanks again for the help/input.

Jon

Comment: Can you clarify why you can't do thousands of invalidations a day? Do you mean that it's too expensive? In any case, the way this is typically handled with dynamic content is to use a short cache time—short enough that you don't mind the possibility of stale content—and rely on conditional requests instead. You still need the network request to confirm that the file hasn't changed, but you don't have to re-transfer the actual data until the content itself has changed.

Comment: Another approach is to use a constant top-level URL (with a cache time of 0) that embeds the actual content as a sub-resource. That sub-resource would then use filename versioning in conjunction with long cache times. That is how static files are typically handled. It's less common with dynamic content in favor of the approach mentioned above.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry: Yes, overall cost is the factor for invalidations. Starting out I won't have too many, but as the number of entries (and authors) increase, the cost will increase.  The dynamic side to my application is handled as far as page-performance and fresh content, it's the static pages where I'm analyzing my possibilities. As far as embedding the content as a sub-resource, I think you just found my next area of research/testing.   I appreciate your help.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry: A clarification is needed (as I re-read my comment(s)) in that when I say "static" I mean a pre-rendered HTML document that is composed of not only the JS/CSS and other dependent files, but the page content itself.  Think of a static-site generator's output.  I am analyzing if I'll be serving those "static" pages of HTML on CloudFront, or via another infrastructure.  Thanks again.

Comment: I see what you mean, but since the contents of the page can change at any time, and since you don't want to serve stale content, the page is "dynamic" from a caching perspective. No matter how you structure things, some resource on your origin server is going to have to respond to every hit on your webpage if you're not willing to tolerate state content. Good luck.

Comment: @KevinChristopherHenry: Very true. I'm now revisiting the idea of a CDN with cache policies for various page types, with an invalidation call upon an author's entry update.  I'm recalculating the CF cost for this, as well as looking at other services/solutions.  CloudFlare, for example, doesn't seem to charge for invalidating a URL, and has built it into their API. A load-balanced, EC2-based Varnish solution perhaps. I'm still very much researching to find my "ideal", but will most likely have to find the middle between "ideal" and "realistic".  Thanks for the input, it's helped quite a lot.

Comment: For those interested in my earlier comment about the CloudFlare API's endpoint for clearing a file's cache by URL:   https://api.cloudflare.com/#zone-purge-files-by-url   I'll be testing that next, (tonight most likely).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***"I would expect then that the next Request to CloudFront, before the 20-minute TTL and with the old `if-none-match` value, would then prompt the CloudFront to see the `ETag` is different and send the latest version."***

That is a mistaken assumption. CloudFront doesn't know that you updated S3. You told it not to check with the origin until the TTL has expired. So it's just serving the old file until the TTL has expired and it sees the new one that you uploaded to S3. (Note that this doesn't have anything to do with `ETags`).

CloudFront does offer ways to [invalidate the cache](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/Invalidation.html), and you can read more about how to combine that with S3 updates in [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12783009/does-amazon-s3-send-invalidation-signals-to-cloudfront).

Comment: Very clear.  Thanks Kevin.  
I've updated my entry with an experiment of sorts where I've turned CloudFront caching off, and am viewing how the ETag is used.   
I am seeing an HTTP status of 200 come back for the 1st call to the CF, with 304's on all subsequent calls.  A change to the same file will reset its ETag value, therefore giving another status of 200 on the next call, with 304's for all after.   
Am I correct that CloudFront is saying (in so many words) "Nothing's changed, no need to send the file.  Use the Browser's version"?

Comment: @JonDCruz: Yes, that is how a server tells a client that its version of a resource is current. Note that this is not something CloudFront specific, it's a general mechanism of HTTP known as [conditional requests](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7232).

Answer (score 0):

We can enable bucket versioning and  object with new etag is picked up by the cloudfront